# Passing an Object to Fragment or DialogFragment upon Instantiation

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-dialogfragment

I'm trying to work out the correct way to pass in an Object to a [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html) or [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html) without breaking the '[empty constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#Fragment%28%29)' rule.

For example I have created a custom View and for each one I instantiate I want to associate a DiaglogFragment. This DialogFragment will be used to display controls with which the user can alter certain aspects of the custom View it is associated with. Because View is an Object I understand I cannot use [setArguments()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setArguments%28android.os.Bundle%29).

I could implement a newInstance(View) method of my DialogFragment i.e. Factory pattern but then what happens if my Fragment is saved by the system and then restored at a later date? As far as I can tell there will be no reference to the View object?

Could someone tell me if I am using Fragments in the wrong way or is there way to achieve passing in an object to the Fragment which will also cope with the system reconstructing it at a later time.

Comment: Add a setter to your fragment then call that setter after `new Fragment()`? But you don't want to be setting views. You want to tell the fragment what it needs to show and it should be able to come up with the views itself. If the activity is doing that work then it probably means you don't have your fragments and activities properly split up.

Comment: The fragment isn't going to show the View it's merely closely associated to it. The Fragment however needs to pass data back to the View (such as which Radio button is selected)

Comment: The proper way to do this is to create an interface that the activity implements and the fragment can call methods on. Basically the activity should orchestrate any interactions between fragments and other views in the activity.

Comment: Yes you made me realise that I'm using Fragments in a way that I should not. What I can do is pass in the id of the View and also the fragment that contains that view. When needed my DialogFragment can call back to the containing Activity to pass on the data.

Answer (score 16):

In your `DialogFragmnet` class, you create two methods:

1. `newInstance` to make instance of your `DialogFragment`
2. setter to initialize your object

and add `setRetainInstance(true);` in `onCreate`

```
public class YourDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    ComplexVariable complexVar;

    public static YourDialogFragment newInstance(int arg, ComplexVariable complexVar) {
        YourDialogFragment frag = new MoveSongDialogFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("count", arg);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        frag.setComplexVariable(complexVar);
        return frag;
    }

    public void setComplexVariable(ComplexVariable complexVar) {
        this.complexVar = complexVar;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }
}
```

then, to show the dialog

```
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();

Fragment prev = manager.findFragmentByTag("yourTag");
if (prev != null) {
    ft.remove(prev);
}

// Create and show the dialog.
DialogFragment newFragment = YourFragmentDialog.newInstance(argument, yourComplexObject);
newFragment.show(ft, "yourTag");
```

Comment: Not sure that this is a good approach since your DialogFragment could be restored automatically (e.g. during rotation) and then *yourVar* value will be null.        So DialogFragment will be rendered incorrectly in case of its automatic instantiation by the system.

Comment: Seems like putting serialized object inside Fragment's args is the only good solution. Or standard communication using getActivity()+interface approach.

Comment: @goRGon you are right if you have not called in fragment's onCreate setRetainInstance(true);

Comment: Updated answer and added setRetainInstance(true); for future reference

Comment: or store the complex var in architecture components ViewModel

Answer (score 3):

You can pass Object in the Bundle extras as Parcelable Objects (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html ) and pass them to Bundle in the `onCreateView(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. You can although save them if the user flips the screen.

**EDIT:** [this](http://blog.logicexception.com/2012/09/a-parcelable-tutorial-for-android.html) Parcelable tutorial was quite good!

Another way is getting the data object from your ParentActivity, but I'm not sure if this is a good way (but it works..)

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mYourObject = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getYourObject();
}
```

you have to create a Getter in your Activity for that

```
public YourObject getYourObject(){
   return mYourObecjt;
}
```

But I guess Parcelables are the better way, because you can reuse your Fragments without any dependencies...

Comment: Not sure Parcelable is what I need but having read through the link I realise I probably didn't make my question clear. I need a reference to an actual object. A Parcelable object is a reconstruction/clone of an actual object? I need the reference so I can change the View in real time.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use a nice **JSON** library like GSON or **Genson** for serializing objects - it is my goto approach for any remotely complex object. GSON is slightly more compact for simple operations but if you have any sort of inheritance / polymorphism in your views, I would highly recommend Genson. You can have a ctr with argument aslong as you document them.

https://code.google.com/p/genson/ - Get the JAR in the download section.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've realised that I just need a reference to the actual object so any form of serialisation over complicates matters. I just need to communicate via the activity which is the inended way.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my need with sharepreference. YuzdeDataUser  is my Custom clas that I take it onClickItemListener from My Listview

**How to Send**

```
  YuzdeDataUser clickedObj = (YuzdeDataUser) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            //clickedObj.setTarihim();
            SharedPreferences shp = getSharedPreferences("sam", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shp.edit();

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(clickedObj);
            editor.putString("yoklamaList", json);
            editor.commit();

            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            AylikRaporPop userPopUp = new AylikRaporPop();
            userPopUp.show(fragmentManager, "sam");
```

**How to Receive**

```
    SharedPreferences shp = parent.getSharedPreferences("sam", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = shp.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = shp.getString("yoklamaList", "");
    YuzdeDataUser user = gson.fromJson(json, YuzdeDataUser.class);
    if (user != null) {
        txt_ad.setText(user.getAd());
        txt_tur_tarih.setText(Util.getInstance(parent).writeNameOfTur(user.getTur_id()));
        txt_var.setText("" + user.getVar());
        txt_gorevli.setText("" + user.getGorevli());
        txt_yok.setText("" + user.getYok());

    }
```