# Custom DialogFragment - Screen Rotation Crash - Fragment XXX has not been attached yet

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I am stuck with this problem from few hours now.

I have a Android App, There is Activity A. This activity has bottom navigation drawer, that uses view pager, I have 3 views, account, contact and notes.

On each view you can see list of items, as in contacts you can see list of contacts added, on notes you can see list of notes added and so on.

There is fab icon on every fragment that is basically add/edit button, when clicked it opens a dialogfragment which is used for editing or adding contacts or notes.

My problem is that I can only open my Edit dialog for  Contact and notes one time. Once you rotate the screen 2-3 times, I get the error .. Fragment ContactDialogXXXX has not been attached yet.

```
fun editContactDialog(contact: Contact?) {

    val transaction  = childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    val previous = childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(ContactEditDialog.name)

    if (previous != null) {
        transaction.remove(previous)
    }

    val dialog = ContactEditDialog.getInstance(contact, accountId)
    dialog.show(transaction, ContactEditDialog.name)
}
```

I am using this above method to open dialog everytime. and only  gives me error that Fragment XX has not been attached yet. after rotation. I have even done below thing from given links with no luck.

- set retainInstance to true in onCreate
- also added this snippet

> ```
> override fun onDetach() {
>      super.onDetach()
>      callbacks = null
>  }
> ```

I did add

> ```
>     if (!isAdded)
>         return
> ```

but adding above line in that method only stops the crash but my dialog does not open then.

I have searched everywhere online, looked into all possible combinations on stackoverflow but my problem persists.

tried solutions from below places:
[Passing an Object to Fragment or DialogFragment upon Instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16405825/passing-an-object-to-fragment-or-dialogfragment-upon-instantiation)

https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-dialogfragment#styling-dialogs

What am I missing? Is there another way of doing it? A better way of creating error prone Custom Dialog Fragments?

Comment: At a glance of your code, in `editContactDialog` are you missing a call to `Commit`, that is, `transaction.Commit()`?

Comment: after .show() statement? I will try that now and see if it works.

Comment: didn't work.. gave me error that it has already been committed. and I searched and apparently .show method does commit too.

The other thing I noticed is .. I tried to use fragmentManager. So after rotating screen the fragmentManager is null.
and if I use childFragmentMAnager, after rotation that childFragmentManager is in invalid state that is it has not yet been attached.
Don't know what that means but maybe someone knows.

Comment: after long long struggle trying to figure it out.. I found out one thing that is affecting .. after screen orientation changes.. my all the the fragments inside view pager lose context and fragment managers.. all becomes null thought they are still shown .. still looking for how to solve that.

Comment: Please show how you configure the `ViewPager` and the `Adapter`.